# Calculate percentage of running total with N largest numbers in non-continuous array of cells into a continuous array of cells

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, cumulative-sum

I am trying to calculate the running total in percent on a non-continuous range, in a continuous array based on their internal ranking (from 1-10).

I've managed to calculate the percentage separately for each "ranking" cell with the formula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($Y$25:$Y$110)>=LARGE(ABS($Y$25:$Y$110);AX25));ABS($Y$25:$Y$110))/SUM(ABS($Y$25:$Y$110))
```

where

- column Y is the data range.
- column AX is the ranking from 1 to 10 - e.g. `AX25` being 1 and `AX34` being 10.

This will be able to do the job, however i would rather have this done as an array formula where all the "ranking" cells are calculated together. I've tried that below by using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($Y$25:$Y$110)>=LARGE(ABS($Y$25:$Y$110);$AX$25:$AX$34));ABS($Y$25:$Y$110))/SUM(ABS($Y$25:$Y$110))
```

I want to use this as a condition in the following array formula calculating the top 10 values in a specific column in the data range:

```
=IF(INDEX($AH$25:$BL$110;MATCH(LARGE(ABS(OFFSET($AH$25:$AH$110;;S23));$Q$25:$Q$34);ABS(OFFSET($AH$25:$AH$110;;S23));0);S23+1)>0;
INDEX($AH$25:$BL$110;MATCH(LARGE(ABS(OFFSET($AH$25:$AH$110;;S23));$Q$25:$Q$34);ABS(OFFSET($AH$25:$AH$110;;S23));0);S23+1);0)
```

where

- Column AH:BL is the data range (expanded from only column Y in the first formula).
- Row 23 indicates the offset number in order to reach the correct column in the data range.
- Column Q is the ranking numbers from 1-10.

**Added Mock-up**

[image: Added Mock-Up]

The red fields illustrate that the cumulative value of N rank is above 80% of the total in the given range, hence they should be zero/"".

Comment: Interesting problem, can you elaborate a bit on how you need to use this? i.e. what do you hope to achieve with the array formula?

Comment: Yes, I want N to be a maximum of 10 (so top 10), but only as long as the cumulative value is below X% of the total value. Was considering it would be better to use percentile, if a number alone is higher than X% - any thoughts?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The reason you're getting the error is because the formula tries to find matching cells in both columns (i.e. you have 86 cells in Y column and only 10 cells in the AX column).
If you only need the cumulative top 10, then replacing *AX25* with *10* would give you that information. However, making it dynamic in the range 1-10 requires something more.

Comment: The issue is I already have a continuous array calculating the top 10 numbers in the non-continuous range. However i want this array to stop (be zero) once the cumulative value of N is above 80%

Comment: Could you create a mock-up of your expected results and then we can maybe fill in where there are gaps?

Comment: Mock-up added to the question.